# Moving a map from an Array with Keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'd like to create a map with an array... I saw a lot of tutorials about platform game creatio on flash, but no one with the map moving.

So, I try to do it by myself.
Before moving my map, I've to create it, and THAT's my problem !
So, I let you have a see on three layers code and make your opinion on.

Flash announce me an error #1009, he can't access to a property or method of null object reference and I don't see once ?

```
at Sansnom_fla::MainTimeline/createMap()
at Sansnom_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Layer 1

```
var grid:MovieClip = new MovieClip();   

// liste d'affichage
addChild(grid)                      

createMap()
```

Layer 2

```
function createMap():void{
    for (var i:int=0; i<20; i++){                               
        for (var j:int=0; j<15; j++){                           

            var T:int = 32
            var dT:int = T*.5
            var f:int = map[j][i]

            if(f>0) {
                var t:block = new block()
                t.x= i*T;       
                t.y= j*T;       
                t.gotoAndStop(f)        
                grid.addChild(t)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Layer 3

```
 var map:Array = [
                     [1,1,1,1,1,1,10,0,0,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,6,1,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,3,1],
                     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                     ]

var stock:Array = [
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                 ]
```

Thanks a lot !
Ps : As you could learn, block is a movieClip where once frame is a particular block.

Comment: Are you sure map is not null in your layer 2? what is the line given in the stacktrace?

Comment: No, there a solid, let me try with just "1",
The stacktrace : "TypeError: Error #1009: Il est impossible d'accéder à la propriété ou à la méthode d'une référence d'objet nul. (It's impossible to access to a null object reference method)
 at Sansnom_fla::MainTimeline/createMap()
 at Sansnom_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you splitting code between layers? Don't do that. Also you are calling `map` in layer 2 before it even exists yet *(it isn't created until layer 3's code is run)* so my recommendation is to stick it all into 1 layer, on 1 frame.

Then adjust your code order like so:

```
var map:Array = [
                 [1,1,1,1,1,1,10,0,0,11,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,6,1,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                 [1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,3,1],
                 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                 ];

var stock:Array = [
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
             [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
             ];

function createMap():void{
    for (var i:int=0; i<20; i++){                               
        for (var j:int=0; j<15; j++){                           

            var T:int = 32
            var dT:int = T*.5
            var f:int = map[j][i]

            if(f>0) {
                var t:block = new block()
                t.x= i*T;       
                t.y= j*T;       
                t.gotoAndStop(f)        
                grid.addChild(t)
            }
        }
    }
}

var grid:MovieClip = new MovieClip();   

// liste d'affichage
addChild(grid);

createMap();
```

Also don't forget the `;` character, you have a habit of missing them out. Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: @Eustache thats what I told you :D